# Memory and mass storage capability in Java Card

Tags: memory, embedded, smartcard, javacard

I am developing a cardlet in Java Card and I need to store a lot of data.

Concerning the card's technical key features I can read:

- 78Ko EEPROM
- Min. 2GB flash memory

**My question concerns the flash memory access : How to store datas into it ?**

In my applet, I instantiate persistants byte arrays to store my datas but proceding this way, I use the EEPROM.

I'm discovering smart cards and I'm a little lost.

Comment: Where did you get a smartcard with 2GB persistent memory? Is it a smart microSD card? If so, I think you will have to use some proprietary API (if it exists), there is no support for this in JavaCard...

Comment: Yes, it is a smart microSD card (Mobile Security Card SE 1.0 from G&D)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see any smart microSD card yet. May I ask you to attack it's picture also please? :) Is it exactly like usual mcroSD memory cards or there is some differences?

Comment: Well I can't take photo at this moment but there is nothing special, it looks like an usual microSD memory card.
On the following link you have an image : http://business.chip.de/news/microSD-Karte-macht-Smartphones-sicherer_41552970.html ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test if the optional package `javacardx.external.MemoryAccess` is implemented to gain access. You won't be able to directly use the memory for your Applet.

To you use it you would probably have to execute something similar to:

```
javacardx.external.Memory.getMemoryAccessInstance(MEMORY_TYPE_EXTENDED_STORE,  short[] memorySize, short memorySizeOffset)
```

Note that the Java Card implementation is mainly concerned with security applications. Storing data directly in unprotected flash is probably not the way to go.

The manufacturer may have implemented a proprietary API to access the flash. Better ask your vendor if the above solution does not work.